# JSONSerialization with URLSession.shared.dataTask errors

Tags: json, swift, url

As a part of teaching myself Swift, I am working on a Weather App. I am currently attempting to integrate weather alerts. I use a struct called AlertData to initialize data returned from the API call to weather.gov after serializing the returned data from an API call. Or, at least that is the plan. I have modeled my classes off of other classes that request data from weather.gov, but to get an alert, I need to be able to send variable parameters in my dataTask. I use the URL extension from Apple's App Development with Swift (code below) and have the code set to issue the parameters with the users current location to get alerts where the user is currently.

My problem comes when I attempt to construct the API call to weather.gov  in my AlertDataController class(code below). Xcode keeps throwing different errors and I am not sure why. I would like to use a guard statement as I have in my code below, but that throws an error of "Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type '[[String : Any]]'" in my code where shown. It also throws the same error when I make it a simple constant assignment after unwrapping as the extension returns an optional URL.

The same code works flawlessly when I construct the URL from a string in the guard statement directly as in:

```
guard let url = URL(string: (baseURL + locationString + stations)) else {
```

What am I missing? Where my error is thrown is inside the dataTask, and regardless of how it got there, the variable url is an unwrapped URL. Thanks in advance.

Controller class:

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

struct AlertDataController {

    func checkWxAlert(location: CLLocation, completion: @escaping (AlertData?) -> Void) {
        let baseURL = URL(string: "https://api.weather.gov/alert")!
        let locationString = "\(location.coordinate.latitude),\(location.coordinate.longitude)"
        var query = [
            "active": "1",
            "point": locationString
        ]

       guard let url = baseURL.withQueries(query) else {

            completion(nil)
            print("Unable to build URL in AlertDataController.checkWxAlert with supplied queries.")
            return
        }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            if let data = data,
                let rawJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data),
                let json = rawJSON as? [String: Any],
                let featuresDict = json["features"] as? [[String: Any]],
                let propertiesArray = featuresDict!["properties"] as? [String: Any] {
Error: Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type '[[String : Any]]'

                let alertData = AlertData(json: propertiesArray)
                completion(alertData)

            } else {
                print("Either no data was returned in AlertDataController.checkWxAlert, or data was not serialized.")

                completion(nil)
                return
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }

}
```

URL extension:

```
import Foundation

extension URL {

    func withQueries(_ queries: [String: String]) -> URL? {
        var components = URLComponents(url: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)
        components?.queryItems = queries.flatMap { URLQueryItem(name: $0.0, value: $0.1) }
        return components?.url
    }

    func withHTTPS() -> URL? {
        var components = URLComponents(url: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)
        components?.scheme = "https"
        return components?.url
    }
}
```

Comment: `featuresDict = json["features"] as? [[String: Any]]` ... You call it a "dictionary" and subsequently try to use it as such, but `[[String: Any]]` is not a dictionary. It is an array of dictionaries. Which is it?

Comment: Why not use the Codable protocol and JSONDecoder?

Comment: @Rob I can send you the other code. That is why this error caught me off guard.

Comment: @Rob Whether you agree with how I named the variable doesn't change the nature of what it is. You are correct that one is an array of dictionaries (actually an array of dictionaries of dictionaries) and the other is a dictionary (dictionary of dictionaries), but I could call them foo and that wouldn't be the cause of the error. Type is inferred.

Comment: @Rob  As to the actual JSON, that is difficult. It won't format in the window here, and as they are weather alerts, I can't post a URL that would be meaningful for very long. However, as to actually parsing the JSON properly, I haven't gotten to the point that I can test it due to the error. However, the JSON I am working with in other parts is formatted similarly, so I am not concerned about the deserialization in and of itself. I can work through that myself.

Comment: @Rob You aren't being difficult, but it isn't the JSONSerialization either. I came to the same realization. When I looked at my other code, I only needed the first element in the array, so my code was `let propertiesArray = featuresDict.first!["properties"] as? [String: Any]`. For some reason, the error didn't pop for a long time after I deleted the .first, and led me astray as to what had caused it. I am currently trying to figure out if I can iterate in the if let statement, or if I drop the iteration inside and test it there. And,, .first is optional as it returns nil if the array is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `featuresDict` is really an array, you cannot use `featuresDict["properties"]` syntax. That subscript with string syntax is only for dictionaries. But you've apparently got an array of dictionaries.

You could iterate through the `featuresDict` array (which I'll rename to `featuresArray` to avoid confusion), you could do that after you finish unwrapping it. Or, if just want an array of the values associated with the `properties` key for each of those dictionaries, then `flatMap` is probably a good choice.

For example:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in

    guard let data = data,
        error == nil,
        let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String: Any],
        let featuresArray = json["features"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
            print("Either no data was returned in AlertDataController.checkWxAlert, or data was not serialized.")

            completion(nil)
            return
    }

    let propertiesArray = featuresArray.flatMap { $0["properties"] }
    let alertData = AlertData(json: propertiesArray)
    completion(alertData)
}
```

Or, if `AlertData` is expecting each of those properties to be, themselves, a dictionary, you might do:

```
let propertiesArray = featuresArray.flatMap { $0["properties"] as? [String: Any] }
```

Just replace that cast with whatever type your `AlertData` is expecting in its array, `json`.

Or, if you're only interested in the first property, you'd use `first` rather than `flatMap`.

Comment: @ Rob I think we are on the right track, but the compiler is complaining. "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[[String : Any]]'" Do I want to use flatMap or filter? What I want to end up with is an array of dictionaries all with the key of properties, and exclude the other dictionaries at the same level as properties. Once this is cracked, it will feed into my struct AlertData.

Comment: Re "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[[String : Any]]'" ... The only way I could imagine you got that error is if your guard statement accidentally had something like `guard ..., let featuresArray = json["features"] as! [[String: Any]] else { ... }`, with `as!` rather than `as?` as shown in my answer. The code in my answer compiles fine for me. I wager that there's some little difference between the above and what you have in your project.

Comment: @Yrb - Re what `flatMap` above does, see https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/ad9b331f9d37927074f4e250f21627a7 for example.

Comment: I have to remember that I am dealing with an array of dictionaries, and that properties itself is a dictionary of dictionaries. After properties, the dictionaries end up being [String: String] so they can be dealt with. The problem I am having with this is that I want it to fail at this line of code as well. Where the error popped up is as I was reading, I hit the second part where you talk about AlertData expecting dictionaries and tried using that in the if let statement. How can I fail this line if I get nil?

Comment: A little time away gives some perspective...flatMap removes nils, so the worst I get is an empty array that I can test for. Marking this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The error

> Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type '[[String : Any]]'

is very clear. It occurs because in the optional binding expression `featuresDict` is already unwrapped when the next condition is evaluated.

Just remove the exclamation mark

```
      ... let propertiesArray = featuresDict["properties"] as? [String: Any] {
```

---

The error is not related at all to the way the URL is created.

Comment: I tried removing the exclamation mark, but I then get the error: Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : Any]]' with an index of type 'String'

Comment: This is also clear because an array `[[String:Any]]` is subscripted by **index** not by key